# enforce password length on ubuntu with pam_cracklib

Tags: ubuntu, pam, password-policy

I was trying to enforce password length to a minimum of 10 using pam_cracklib.

here is my */etc/pam.d/common-password*

```
password        requisite                       pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=10 difok=3 dcredit=1  ocredit=1 ucredit=1
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
```

After setting this, I am able to set passwords with less than 10 characters. I read this as a bug from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/139999

Is there any fix/wayaround/alternative to enforce password length in ubuntu12.04 ?

Comment: What is in `/etc/pam.d/passwd`?

Comment: @include common-password

Comment: I don't know much about this, but if it lets you set an arbitrary password-checker, you could roll your own, which first checks the length and then calls pam_cracklib to do the rest. (Sorry if this is obvious and stupid; I just know a little about what you can do in OpenBSD, not Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to answer "Wrong option, guys" but lookie here:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/139999
> [...]
> Steve Langasek (vorlon) wrote on 2008-07-30:
>
> To set a hard minimum password length, please use the 'min' option to pam_unix instead. The 'minlen' option to pam_cracklib doesn't do what the name suggests it should do.
> I'm confirming this as a documentation bug; the pam_cracklib documentation needs to be made a lot clearer about this.
> [...]

I like to point out that the default comment in /etc/security/pwquality.conf tells us the same, alas using convoluted grammar:

> Minimum acceptable size for the new password (plus one if
> credits are not disabled which is the default). (See pam_cracklib manual.)
> Cannot be set to lower value than 6.

So:

```
min = 10
enforcing = 1
```

or:

```
minlen = 10
dcredit = 0
ucredit = 0
lcredit = 0
ocredit = 0
minclass = 4
enforcing = 1
```

...should do the trick. HTH